# WHM: Moving an account to a new server

Tags: php, cpanel, whm

I have an account on WHM for a PHP web app that's over 50GB in size on a dedicated server, the company decided to move it to a new server, and I was assigned the task.

I would like to know what is the best way to do it, built-in WHM **copy account** function, or creating full backup and restore it to the new server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I assume these 50GB are mostly data, am I right?. So I would first create a backup of the application scripts and deploy them in the new site and make sure everything is running smoothly. Then I see no problem in using the copy account function, since the data transfer between servers is usually way faster than you uploading it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, the account copy function just gzips up your account folder and everything inside, so you might as well use this method as it is likely the same as what you would do manually.

Do make sure you check everything works fine after moving though. It is sometimes a good idea to restrict access to your new site until you have checked it over.